# Random Unanswered question sorting

Tags: feature-request, questions, unanswered-questions, sorting

I think that a feature that sorts all the unanswered questions randomly would be good, as long as it reordered everything every time the page is refreshed. I often browse the newest page,  only to find that I am out of questions that I can answer within five minutes. It would help get attention to old questions that would not be looked at otherwise.

Comment: "out of questions that I can answer within five minutes" - That's actually pretty good. For most people (including myself), that would be "zero minutes".

Comment: The only problem that I can see with this is that there are currently 795,133 unanswered questions, so you're drawing from a pretty large pool of questions, many of which are too old to still be useful.  The system already randomly pokes old, unanswered questions to bring them to the front page.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a SEX-DEX query to do this:

[Random Unanswered Posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84588/random-unanswered-posts)

It has a few problems, such as SE's overly aggressive caching allowing `RAND()` not to function properly (make a simple edit every time you run the script & it should work), and the interface isn't the best, but it does pull down what you want.

Here's the query parameters I used:

- Only Questions
- Zero total answers
- Less than 500 views
- Not closed

And, the most important part

- Selects 15  in-order rows, from a random part of the SE Question heap.

I could have used `ORDER BY newid()`, but that would have cause major performance issues, so I decided to use this instead.

Enjoy the script, and let me know if you have any more requests (besides tag filtering, it turned out to be too complex).